# How to find missing items with GroupBy in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a scenario like this where I have a collection of these items

```
public class Submission {
    public DateTime ProcessedDate { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to check against a collection of usernames, for example:

```
string[] names = new string{"Paul", "John", "George", "Ringo"};
```

I want to find out which dates there are missing submissions for (dates where not all of these user names have an entry). So imagine test data like:

```
var submissions = new List<Submission>();
submissions.Add(new Submission() { ProcessedDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), UserName = "Paul" });
submissions.Add(new Submission() { ProcessedDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), UserName = "John" });
submissions.Add(new Submission() { ProcessedDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), UserName = "George" });
submissions.Add(new Submission() { ProcessedDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), UserName = "Ringo" });
submissions.Add(new Submission() { ProcessedDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 2), UserName = "Paul" });
submissions.Add(new Submission() { ProcessedDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 2), UserName = "John" });
submissions.Add(new Submission() { ProcessedDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 3), UserName = "George" });
submissions.Add(new Submission() { ProcessedDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 3), UserName = "Ringo" });
```

1/1 has submissions for all usernames, but 1/2 and 1/3 are each missing entries, how do I return a collection of the missing ones (both the date missing and the users missing for that date)?

2018-01-02 - George, Ringo

2018-01-03 - Paul, John

Comment: `GroupBy` the date, then check each group to see if there is _not_ `Any` result of `Except`

Comment: @maccettura can that be done in one line? I'm trying to visualize the query but I keep getting stuck on filtering the results of GroupBy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need just the dates, use this query:

```
var result = submissions.GroupBy(o => o.ProcessedDate)
    .Where(o => names.Any(x => !o.Any(s => s.UserName == x)))
    .Select(o => o.Key)
    .ToList();
```

If you require a list of `Submission` objects, use this one:

```
var resultWithSubmissions = submissions.GroupBy(o => o.ProcessedDate)
    .Where(o => names.Any(x => !o.Any(s => s.UserName == x)))
    .SelectMany(o => o)
    .ToList();
```

if you require a list of missing usernames per date, use this query:

```
var resultWithMissingNames = submissions.GroupBy(o => o.ProcessedDate)
    .Where(o => names.Any(x => !o.Any(s => s.UserName == x)))
    .Select(o => new { ProcessedDate = o.Key, MissingNames = string.Join(",", names.Except(o.Select(x => x.UserName)))})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Some other good answers but this is exactly what I was looking for, well done!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
var result = submissions
                 .GroupBy(s => s.ProcessedDate)
                 .Select(g => new { Date = g.Key, Names = names.Except(g.Select(s => s.UserName)) })
                 .Where(g => g.Names.Any());
```

Comment: what about date range ??.. and how its going to return this user missing for this date

Comment: @PranayRana "dates where not all of these user names have an entry" I think they're all in the collection already

Comment: how its going to return this thing `2018-01-02 - George, Ringo, 2018-01-03 - Paul, John` , just want to know ..how user mssing for given day going to be printed

Comment: @vc74: what if the collection is empty? Then every user has submissioned on every date? What if there is a gap? Leaving this aside it doesn't show how to find the missing dates and users.

Comment: @TimSchmelter If `submissions` is empty, there's nothing to group and `result ` will be an empty enumerable, or am I missing something?

Comment: @vc74: sure, you could still group by the date(f.e. last months missing submissions). If all are missing at a date, i think all are missing. But of course could also be that this can be ignored.

Comment: It really depends on what the OP means by "dates where not all of these user names have an entry", if the dates he/she refers to are those from the collection then I believe this answer is correct, but if the dates are from another collection, yours is correct

Comment: @itsme86 That looks like it filters it correctly but I can't see how I get the Date out of it? Like if I iterate that result variable, the first item I can see in the debugger contains 'George' and 'Ringo' which is correct, but how do I know which Date they are associated with?

Comment: @snappymcsnap Updated my answer to include date in result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = new[] { "Paul", "John", "George", "Ringo" };
var dates = new[] { new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), new DateTime(2018, 1, 2),
    new DateTime(2018, 1, 3) };

var missingUsersByDate = submissions
    .GroupBy(s => s.ProcessedDate)
    .Select(g => new { ProcessDate = g.Key,
        MissingUsers = names.Except(g.Select(s => s.UserName)) })
    .Where(g => g.MissingUsers.Any())
    .ToDictionary(k => k.ProcessDate, v => v.MissingUsers);

// Paul, John
var missingUsers = missingUsersByDate[new DateTime(2018, 1, 3)];

// 2018.1.2 -> George, Ringo
// 2018.1.3 -> Paul, John
foreach(var usersDatePair in missingUsersByDate)
{
    DateTime date = usersDatePair.Key;
    string[] users = usersDatePair.Value.ToArray();
}
```

This method groups the submissions by date and uses an anonymous types to store information about the date and the missing users.
This result is then filtered to remove dates with no missing students and then is returned as a dictionary.